# Use gdal_grid with geopackage

Tags: gdal, geopackage, gdal-grid

I'm using `gdal_grid` to interpolate IDW mode with points in GPKG format but I don't know how to write the sequence. I'm using the following code:

```
gdal_grid -zfield "z" -a invdist:power=2.0:smoothin=1.0 -txe 465000 750000  -tye 4852900 4623700  -outsize 6000 5000 -of GTiff -ot Int32 -l "deliverynote_specie_name_E" C:\coberturas\temp\deliverynote_specie_name_E.nitens.gpkg "C:\coberturas\temp\Enitens.tif"
```

But gdal gives me the following error:

> ERROR 1: bad application_id on
>   'C:\coberturas\temp\deliverynote_specie_name_E.nitens.gpkg' Unable to
>   open input datasource
>   "C:\coberturas\temp\deliverynote_specie_name_E.nitens.gpkg". bad
>   application_id on
>   'C:\coberturas\temp\deliverynote_specie_name_E.nitens.gpkg'

I think the problem is how to write the name of point layer of my GPKG.

on the other hand, how could I define the spatial resolution of 100 meters?

[image]

Comment: There is a point in your filename - have you tried removing it?

Comment: In the gpkg file are only point layer, with 178 points en this case. Add img

Comment: I think @Erik is referring to the "dot/period" in your filename: `deliverynote_specie_name_E.nitens.gpkg`

Comment: I deleted the point of the name file. The result was the same.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\GDAL>gdal_grid -zfield "z" -a invdist:power=2.0:smoothin=1.0 -txe 465000 750000  -tye 4852900 4623700  -outsize 6000 5000 -of GTiff -ot Int32 -l "deliverynote_specie_name_E" "C:\coberturas\temp\deliverynote_specie_name_E_globulus.gpkg" "C:\coberturas\temp\Enitens.tif"
ERROR 1: bad application_id on 'C:\coberturas\temp\deliverynote_specie_name_E_globulus.gpkg'
Unable to open input datasource "C:\coberturas\temp\deliverynote_specie_name_E_globulus.gpkg".
bad application_id on 'C:\coberturas\temp\deliverynote_specie_name_E_globulus.gpkg'`

Comment: what is the output of `ogrinfo deliverynote_specie_name_E_globulus.gpkg`

Comment: `C:\coberturas\temp>ogrinfo deliverynote_specie_name_E_globulus.gpkg
ERROR 1: bad application_id on 'deliverynote_specie_name_E_globulus.gpkg'
ERROR 1: bad application_id on 'deliverynote_specie_name_E_globulus.gpkg'
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `deliverynote_specie_name_E_globulus.gpkg' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> SDTS
  -> TIGER
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> VRT`

Comment: looks like it's a problem with the input gpkg and not gdal_grid. You will need to try to fix the file, perhaps see if you can open the gpkg in qgis.

Comment: I tested the file in qGIS and it seems that there is no problem, it opens without problems.
I think it can be a topic of gdal drivers with gpkg.
When I use Gdal IDW grid inside QGIS it interpolates without problems, but I need to perform the operation outside of QGIS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100147/discussion-between-dmci-and-alejandro-chamizo-de-castro).

Comment: "Bad application_id" error means that there is something wrong in the GeoPackage. If you can open the data with QGIS try to save it as a copy into a new GeoPackage and try again.